# Connection refused and then an autorefresh when accessing site

Tags: http, https

I have a [website](http://mutanalyst.com/) that is registered at GoDaddy and is hosted in Dropbox that blinks a Connection refused before connecting to the site (in Chrome) and I cannot figure it out.

I am aware that the site is not accessible by https due to the fact that I had to commit to either http or https in the forwarding with masking (GoDaddy has a dropdown menu, so I cannot simply use the unspecified `src=//dl.dropbox.com/blablabla` trick and I cannot drop the masking as `.htcaccess` does not work on Dropbox folders I think —I have asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904341/do-htaccess-files-work-on-dropbox-as-a-webhost)—). But I think this issue is unrelated to that as it should not affect a regular http connection. The problem is, I cannot figure it out.

The paper I submitted for publication got declined at the editorial first step as "the website didn't load" —no unusual browser opened the website that day—, so it is a worse problem that I thought.

I really want to both avoid paying a subscription and avoid ads courtesy of a free webhost, but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was a problem with the GoDaddy redirect and Dropbox when it was unspecified that it was http. https would not work.
However, it seems to have resolved itself, but it is still slow. I have another site on google drive and that runs much faster. So I would recommend that in the first place.